# result_array value are not showing inside foreach loop in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli

I simply fire a select query using Codeigniter where all values are showing when I am using `print_r` function but when I use `foreach` loop then no value is showing I don't know what is the problem is? How can I fix this problem?

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_detail');
    $where = "jid='".$jid_final."' and cid='".$cid_final."' and offer='1'";
    $this->db->where($where);
    $sql_user = $this->db->get();
    $result_user = $sql_user->result_array();
    print_r($result_user);
    foreach($result_user as $row_user)
    {

        $user_data = '<tr>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['uid'].'</td>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['fname'].' '.$row_user['lname'].'</td>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['email'].'</td>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['phone'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
    echo $user_data;
```

Thank You

Comment: there is data in table?

Comment: yes, when I use `print_r($result_user);` it shows data but inside foreach loop, it shows nothing @DevsiOdedra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Below query, need to check if data in table or not and then pass it to foreach loop.**

```
 $user_data = '';
 $this->db->select('*');
    $where = "jid='".$jid_final."' and cid='".$cid_final."' and offer='1'";
    $this->db->where($where, NULL, FALSE);
    $result_user = $this->db->get('user_detail')->result_array();

    if($result_user) {
    foreach($result_user as $row_user)
    {

        $user_data .= '<tr>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['uid'].'</td>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['fname'].' '.$row_user['lname'].'</td>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['email'].'</td>
                        <td class="td">'.$row_user['phone'].'</td>
                    </tr>';
    }
     echo $user_data;
    } else {
     echo "no data found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to concatenate the values with `.`

```
$user_data = '';
if(isseet($result_user) && count($result_user) > 0){
foreach($result_user as $row_user)
{

    $user_data .= '<tr>
                    <td class="td">'.$row_user['uid'].'</td>
                    <td class="td">'.$row_user['fname'].' '.$row_user['lname'].'</td>
                    <td class="td">'.$row_user['email'].'</td>
                    <td class="td">'.$row_user['phone'].'</td>
                </tr>';
}
    echo $user_data;
}else{
    echo 'Record not found';
}
```